# How to keep taking entry until user presses space?

Tags: c++

I was making a code for a mathematical equation while i needed to take input from the user until he wants. Ive just been trying to put a while loop for user entry but i doesn't seems ending!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{ 
 int x,y,counter=0,n=0,X=0,Y=0,S_X,S_Y;


  cout<<"Enter space to end entry \n";
  cout<<"Enter x and y: \n";

    for(int i=0; x!=' ' ; i++) // sum of X and Y entries!
       {
           cout<<"x: ";
           cin>>x;


           cout<<"y: ";
           cin>>y;


           counter++;

           X=X+x;

            Y=Y+y;

    }
     n=counter;

   // X=X+11;
   // Y=Y+11;


  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Presses as in presses down on but does not release, or presses as in "types"?

Comment: One issue is that the input is buffered and the content only returned to the program after the User presses the "Enter" key.

Comment: Interesting fun fact: the default behaviour of `>>` discards all whitespace.

Comment: Another issue is that spaces are ignored when reading in numeric input.

Comment: any other number or key i can keep instead of space?

Comment: @Hassaan Read a string value using `std::getline()` in first place, and check the input. If it's different from `` `` use `std::istringstream` to parse the number.

Comment: It's more than that. You cannot use `cin` for this. It is too simple. You need something that can read characters without requiring enter.

Comment: @user4581301 Which isn't supported by the standard library at all, just to mention.

Comment: The path of least resistance will be something along the lines of [the Curses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library))

Comment: Discarding portability, `getch` from conio.h and reading everything up to the first space into a `std::istringstream` that you then parse would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined x has int so it will never equal `' '`.

( Unless user enters the numeric value of `' '` of your current character set used (e.g. ASCII, EBCDIC etc.))